# IWebbrowser2: Using a Uint8array (filling without looping)

Tags: c++, windows, com, arraybuffer, iwebbrowser2

I can create a Uint8array in an IWebbrowser2 window:

```
IHTMLWindow2 window = ...;
DISPID dispid_uint8array = ...;

VARIANT self;
self.vt = VT_NULL;

VARIANT length;
length.vt = VT_I4;
length.lVal = 100;

VARIANT args[2] = { self, length };
DISPID named_args[1] = { DISPID_THIS };

DISPPARAMS params;
params.rgvarg = args;
params.rgdispidNamedArgs = named_args;
params.cArgs = 2;
params.cNamedArgs = 1;

VARIANT result;
result.vt = VT_EMPTY; 
HRESULT hr = container->Invoke(
    dispid_uint8array, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
    DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, &result, nullptr, nullptr
);

assert(hr == S_OK);
assert(result.vt == VT_DISPATCH);

IDispatch my_new_uint8array = result.pdispVal;
```

Now I can set items fields of `my_new_uint8array` using `IDispatch::Invoke(..., DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, ...)` in a loop.

But isn't there a proper proper interface to fill the whole buffer with just one call? E.g. can I somehow retrieve the contained buffer?

Is there a definition of the interface somewhere, something like `IUint8Array`?

Comment: Aren't these array more javascript (chakra) things? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/chakra-hosting/jscreatetypedarray-function I'm curious how do you get that dispid_uint8array in the first place?

Comment: @SimonMourier, I simply used `window->GetIDsOfNames(...)` supplying `"Uint8Array"`.

Comment: Would you have a reproducing project ready, by any chance?

Comment: `UInt8Array` (more generally, Typed Arrays) started out in WebGL (see [Typed Arrays: Binary Data in the Browser](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/)), and have been adopted by other APIs, like JavaScript (see [JavaScript typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)).

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get an early-binding IUnknown* interface. You should be using IDispatchEx with DISPATCH_CONSTRUCT I guess, or use the other DataView object. I can't help much because my tests don't get me a dispid from the IHTMLWindow2 for some reason ... hence my question on the reproducing project :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier, the setup is just too huge and not mine to share, sorry! :-/ I posted the answer I came up with, but it's an odd one I daresay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an incredibly ugly hack: Using the ArrayBuffer of a `<canvas>`. I'll only post the pseudo code, because the full C++, including error checking, unwrapping etc, is just too long:

**Prelude:**

- `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` was set to `11001`
- `IWebBrowser2::get_ReadyState` returns `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`
- `IHTMLDocument6::get_documentMode` returns `11`
- `IHTMLDocument5::get_compatMode` returns `"CSS1Compat"`
- `IHTMLDocument2 *doc` and `IHTMLWindow2 *win` are set.
- I use simple strings in my pseudo code, but you have to use `BSTR`s of course!
- You might have to `queryInterface` once or twice, so that the results fit.
- Don't ignore errors!

**How to get a "Uint8Array":**

```
ULONG len_in_dwords = (LENGTH_I_WANT + 3) / 4;

IHTMLCanvasElement *canvas = doc->createElement("canvas");
ICanvasRenderingContext2D *context = canvas->getContext("2d");
ICanvasPixelArrayData *array_data = context->createImageData(len_in_dwords, 1);

// use this variable for interfaces that accept an ArrayBuffer
IDispatch *array_buffer = Get property "buffer" of array_data;

// use this variable to edit the content:
BYTE *byte_buffer;
ULONG buffer_length_in_bytes;
array_data->GetBufferPointer(&byte_buffer, &buffer_length_in_bytes);

// no need for that anymore:
canvas->Release();
context->Release();
array_data->Release();
```

The `ArrayBuffer array_buffer` has always a size divisible by four. That works for me, but might not work for other use cases. You can use `array_buffer`'s method [`slice(0, LENGTH_I_WANT)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice) to remove the extra bytes after memcpy'ing to `byte_buffer`.